# How to add data to Airflow DAG Context?

Tags: airflow

We are working with airflow. We have something like 1000+ DAGS.

To manage DAG errors we use the same `on_error_callback` function to trigger alerts.

Each DAG is supposed to have context information, that could be expressed as constants, that I would like to share with the alerting stack.

Currently, I am only able to send the `dag_id` I retrieve from the context, via `context['ti'].dag_id`, and eventually the `conf` (parameters).

Is there a way to add other data (constants) to the context when declaring/creating the DAG?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass params into the context.

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='example_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    params={
        "param1": "value1",
        "param2": "value2"
    }
)
```

These are available in the
**context**

```
  # example task that quickly outputs the context
  start = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'start',
    python_callable = lambda **context: print(context)
  )

  # outputs the context, in the conf dictionary you will see
  # 'params': {'param1': 'value1'},
```

or via **jinja templates**
`{{params.param1}}`

Answer (score 0):

define variables within a DAG and access variables by {{}} [ref](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html)

Example ( with PROJECT_ID variable)

```
with models.DAG(
    ...
    user_defined_macros={ "PROJECT_ID" : PROJECT_ID } 
) as dag:
    projectId = "{{PROJECT_ID}}"
```